# Google Container Engine Load Balancer Issue With Session Affinity

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have 3 Nginx pods running on the Google GKE Kubernetes cluster. I have exposed these pods to the external internet using the Kubernetes service with Load Balancer option (TCP Level 4). Sticky sessions are turned on using the SessionAffinity:ClientIP option.

When I access the external URL, the requests are forwarded to the same internal Nginx pod as expected from the SessionAffinity config. However if I keep the browser idle for about 3 minutes and then access the external URL again, the request goes to another Nginx pod. Why is this happening?  Is there a SessionAffinity expiry or timeout that I can configure in GKE Load Balancer?

My Nginx Yaml,

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      replicas: 3
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: nginx
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nginx
            image: nginx:1.7.9
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

My Service yaml for external load balancer,

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: live
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: name2
          port: 80
          targetPort: 80
          nodePort: 31080
      selector:
        app: nginx
      type: LoadBalancer
      sessionAffinity: ClientIP
```

Comment: My guess is that the IP that is used is not the IP of the client, but the IP of the node balancer node(s). I don't know on GKE but I had this issue on CoreOS nodes at some point. Check the headers to see if the client IP is effectively forwarded properly.

Comment: As I said, the sessionAffinity attribute does work for about 3 minutes. This indicates that the load balancer is able to forward to the correct sticky pod at least for first 3 minutes.  I suspect that the Google Network Load balancer has some sort of expiry when it comes to IP based stickiness. Unfortunately I am yet to find any documentation to back it up.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?